# Creating extension method for _context to detach local entity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get HttpPut request working, but the line below throws exception because local StockItem is not detached yet.

```
_context.Entry(StockItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

So, I need to detach local StockItem before modifying it. The StockItem entity looks like this:

```
public class StockItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public Product Product { get; set; }

        public int StockId { get; set; }

        public DateTime BestBy { get; set; }

        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create an extension to reuse it in other HttpPut requests. I found this code snippet that almost working:

```
public static class Detacher
{
    public static void DetachLocal<T>(this WebAppDbContext context, int entryId)
where T : class, IIdentifier
    {
        //find local entity by Id
        var local = context.Set<T>()
            .Local
            .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Id.Equals(entryId));
        if (!(local==null))
        {
            //detach it
            context.Entry(local).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
        }
    }
}

public interface IIdentifier
{ 
        int Id { get; set; }

}
```

But if I pass my StockItem type into this extension I get an error

```
_context.DetachLocal<StockItem>(id);
```

> CS0311 The type 'WebApi.Entities.StockItem' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'Detacher.DetachLocal(WebAppDbContext, int)'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'WebApi.Entities.StockItem' to
>   'WebApi.IIdentifier'.

Comment: `!(local==null)` A simpler alternative is `(local!=null)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the interface

```
public interface IIdentifier
{  
    int Id { get; set; }
```

Now your entity

```
public class StockItem
```

Does it implement the interface? No.

Could it, possibly? Yes. It has all required members (the `Id`).

Replace

```
public class StockItem
```

with

```
public class StockItem : IIdentifier
```

then.

Comment: Thank you for quick response! Works like a charm, will accept this answer in few minutes